# Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException trying to insert an Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Wiith this function I'm trying to update if the enitity exists(that works) and insert if the entity doens't exists

```
private function updateDatabaseAnswer($client, $survey, $answer, $question){
            $storage = $this->di->find('storage');
            $query = "select sa.id "
                            ."from survey_answers as sa "
                            ."join survey_database_answers as sda "
                            ."on sa.id = sda.id "
                            ."join answers as a "
                            ."on a.id = sda.id_answer "
                            ."where id_client= ".$client->getId()." "
                            ."and id_question = ".$question->getId()." "
                            ."and id_survey = ".$survey->getId();

            $result = $storage->executeSQL($query);
            $updated_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
            if(!empty($result))
                $updated_answer->setId($result[0]);

            $updated_answer->setClient($client);
            $updated_answer->setSurvey($survey);
            $updated_answer->setAnswer($answer);
            empty($result)?$storage->persist($updated_answer):$storage->merge($updated_answer);
            $storage->flush();
        }
```

If the entity doesn't exitst I get this message

```
Type: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException

Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO survey_database_answers (id, id_answer) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [7438573, 1533]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7438573' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Tries to insert an id that already exists

Comment: The error looks like setId gets called else where as well. Thus there is already an id known

Comment: setId() is called only when $result is not empty and the  the code makes an update ,that works ,the problem it's on save a new entity , and then  setId() it's not called

Comment: well the shown query has an id, so it must get it from somewhere